# Function documentation lacking information about returned pointers being NULL or non-NULL. What to assume?

Tags: c, openssl

I'm trying to figure out which OpenSSL functions might return NULL pointers and which cannot. Sometimes the documentation clearly states that the function might return NULL, e.g.

**[X509_NAME_get_entry](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_NAME_get_entry.html)**

> X509_NAME_get_entry() returns an X509_NAME pointer to the requested
>   entry or NULL if the index is invalid.

Sometimes they it does not, e.g.

**[X509_get_subject_name](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_get_subject_name.html)**

It only states

> X509_get_subject_name() returns the subject name of certificate x. The returned value is an internal pointer that MUST NOT be freed.

It's unclear (to me) if that means that the pointer is always valid or if it can be NULL, too.

Another example:

**x509_name_entry_get_data**

explains it for version [1.1.1](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data.html)

> X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_object() returns a valid ASN1_OBJECT structure if
>   it is set or NULL if an error occurred.

but not for [1.1.0](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data.html)

A glance at the source code does not help much either as e.g. X509_get_subject_name just returns a member:

```
X509_NAME *X509_get_subject_name(const X509 *a)
{
    return a->cert_info.subject;
}
```

If this member is ever assigned a NULL pointer or not...

The last example makes it seem necessary to add checks to all pointers coming from functions where there is no explicit documentation that the pointer cannot be NULL. I don't want to add pointless pointer checks in the code, but I do not want to use a security related library in a way where missing pointer checks might somehow be exploited.

Does anybody know how to interpret the OpenSSL documentation correctly in this regard? Or is it just horribly inconsistent and one cannot really tell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would trust the manpages and if it says, that a pointer is returned, and it doesn't mention that a NULL pointer may be returned, then you should be able to rely on it, that this indeed is never the case. Otherwise, I would consider it a severe bug (be it in the manpage or in the code) that should be reported.

For the `x509_name_entry_get_data()` the "returned value" section was entirely missing in the 1.1.0 version. This was fixed.

I would indeed play it safe and check every returned pointer for NULL. This also saves your code when the API changes in the future.

If you really do not want that and do not want to rely only on the manpages, you can at least perform a simple check: Create an empty object, call the function in question and check the return value. For example, for an `X509` object:

```
X509 *x509=X509_new();
printf("%p\n", X509_get_subject_name(x509));
```

This indeed gives a valid pointer, so this hints, that the manpage is correct.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Then it should not be used at all, this is of course another viable option. Not trusting the manpages for that reason on one hand, but still using the library, is a very inconsistent behaviour.